# Getting an index error for a single element included

Tags: python, index-error

I keep getting

> IndexError: list index out of range

'in the append line of my code but when I worked through it bit by bit the error only occurs when I include `D[n]` into the equation and I have no idea why.

```
def asgard(A0,G0,D0,p,b,c,k,m):
    n=0
    A=[A0]
    G=[G0]
    D=[D0]

    for n in range(10):
        A.append(round(A[n]+(k*A[n]-0.1*D[n])/5))
        n += 1
        continue
    return A
```

Comment: Hi, could you also add some sample input in your question? And the complete traceback as well! Thanks!

Comment: What values did you send to the function?

Comment: 1) you don't need to increment n, since you are using a `for` loop with `range` anyway 2) similarly no need for continue 3) arrays begin from 0 index, so n elements mean you can only access upto `D[n-1]`. Make these changes and check if it helps.

Comment: In any case, you are not adding anything into the list `D`, so `D[n]` would start giving an error to you every time n is greater than equal to 1.

Comment: Nicole the problem is you start by accessing `A[0]` and `D[0]` in your first iteration then you append A so now the size of A is 2. Next iteration your access `A[1]` which is ok since you appended A in the first iteration but `D[1]` is out of range since array D is still size 1 with 1 element `D[0]`. Instead you should perhaps call `D[0]` always or append some new value into the D array. I cannot answer for sure because I don't know the purpose of your code :) Cheers.